# Undefined Reference to Function()

Tags: c++

So GCC keeps spouting out this error that keeps boggling my mind

`undefined reference to 'GPS::isValidSentence(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'`

my header file `parseNMEA.h` is as follows:

```
#ifndef PARSENMEA_H_211217
#define PARSENMEA_H_211217

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

#include "position.h"

namespace GPS
{
  using std::string;
  using std::vector;
  using std::pair;

  bool isValidSentence(const string &);
}
#endif
```

and my source file `parseNMEA.cpp` is:

```
#include "parseNMEA.h"

using namespace GPS;

bool isValidSentence(const string &n)
{
  string test = n;
  bool result;
  if (test.find("$GP") != string::npos)    //Find the prefix
  {
      if (test.size() > 5)         //Check if it has 3 char identifier
      {
          //check if it has ',' after identifier
          if (test[6] == ',')
          {
              //check for a '*'
              if(test.find("*",7))
              {
                result = true;
              }
          }
      }

  }
  else
      result = false;
  return result;
}
```

Any ideas as to whats going on? I've tried `bool isValidSentence (const string &n)` in the header file but the same error code

Comment: Show your compile command. What do you compile with what flags?

Comment: And after you read your answer, maybe then you will finally understand why `using namespace`, of any kind, [is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), at least not until one has some experience under the belt.

Comment: From the linked question; https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/3747990, in particular the piece related to "A common mistake is forgetting to qualify the name"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using namespace GPS;` only allows you to use names from that namespace as though they were declared in the current scope. But that use does not extend to defining them. So the function definition must be

```
bool GPS::isValidSentence(const string &n)
```

If that doesn't appeal to you, you can wrap the content of the definitions you put inside the `cpp` file in `namespace GPS { }` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the source file, when you do

```
using namespace GPS;
```

you pull the symbols from the `GPS` namespace into the current (global) namespace. But it doesn't actually "use" the namespace. When you define the `isValidSentence` function, it is defined in the *global* namespace, not in the `GPS` namespace.